# Make a network call when textfield has entered

Tags: swift

I have an alertview with textfield, and would like to make call if a user enters something in the text field and confirm it. I am confused how to handle this workflow.

```
 func btnTapped(cell: UICollectionViewCell) {
    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPath(for: cell)
    openAlert()
    // I want to move the following part once user enters textfield in the alertview
    fetchData(urlString: url, data: data[indexPath.row]) { [weak self] (response, error) in
        if error == nil
        {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                //do any ui update here!
                self?.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
     }
  }

  func openAlert(){
    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
    alertController.addTextField { (textField : UITextField!) -> Void in
        textField.placeholder = "Enter reason"
    }

    let saveAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Confirm", style: .default, handler: { alert -> Void in
        if let textField = alertController.textFields?[0] {
            if textField.text!.count > 0 {
                print("Text :: \(textField.text ?? "")")
            }
        }
    })

    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {
        (action : UIAlertAction!) -> Void in })

    alertController.addAction(cancelAction)
    alertController.addAction(saveAction)

    alertController.preferredAction = saveAction

    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to work with the text field delegates and use textFieldDidChange, then anytime the text is changed on the alert, call the API. Here is a quick example:

```
func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {

    // Make API call here

}
```

Then in the completion block for the API call, set whatever data you would like depending on if the API confirmed or did not confirm.

Comment: I want to make API call when text field is not empty and  alert view confirm button clicked. If alerview confirm button clicked and text field is empty, display an alert view to inform user that textfield is empty and API call wont happen.